# Visual Studio 2013 removing a part of html document when publishing?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publishing

Is it possible to automatically remove a part of an html document when publishing?
For example removing all development script files references and include compiled css or js files instead?
For example:

```
<!-- remove these-->
<link href="/app/css/animation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/app/css/common.loaders.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/app/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- include these instead -->
<link href="/app/css/all-files.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use compiler preprocessors like

@{

#if DEBUG

...

#endif

}

or you could use bundles to help you with compression of js files

Comment: bahadir, thanks for answering,
Yes, I'm using bundles to minify my scripts. I guess your solution works only on Razor Views. I'm using a normal static html page because it's a single page application..

Comment: you could use razor to generate that single page, otherwise it will be hard and complicated to achieve what you want